# Facebook RSS application

Tags: php, facebook, rss

How can I make a Facebook RSS application that autoupdates from the provided RSS feeds. 
Of course doing this is trivial for canvas applications, but I need this for showing on the Facebook Page. All the RSS apps I've taken a look at either dont update or dont work on Facebook Pages.

Especially now that infinite session keys are deprecated (and maybe even forbidden).

Answer (score 2):

I specifically said I do not need this for canvas applications (as that is trivial to do), but on Facebook Pages!
This is done with [profile.setFBML](http://wiki.developers.facebook.com/index.php/Profile.setFBML) and data published that way does reside on the facebook servers.

Answer (score 2):

1. Infinite sessions keys [do not exist anymore](http://developers.facebook.com/news.php?blog=1&story=135)
2. Every feed is unique. But even if it weren't, can I just stuff the fbml.refreshRefUrl in a cron job and it will work without session (because I can not get an infinite session)=
   Or maybe I first need to request the offline_access extended permission?
   Is there any way without using cron jobs?

Answer (score 0):

You have two options.

1. Convert your user session (when the user accesses your app manually) to infinite session, then periodically update the profile information for a user. There is some information on how to do this (and what API calls you can make without sessions) [here](http://wiki.developers.facebook.com/index.php/Authorizing_Applications#About_Session_Keys).
2. Create a new "handle" (see [`fb:ref`](http://wiki.developers.facebook.com/index.php/Fb:ref)) for each unique feed and update that handle whenever the feed changes. Handles are key-values pairs that are associated with your app, that you can include inline through FBML. This allows you to do a single call to the API that will update all users subscribed to a given feed.

The second option is probably the best in the long run.